# Excel charting to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, openxml, highcharts

Can anyone suggested approaches to creating JavaScript charts from an MS Excel chart such that colours and other formatting options are preserved? Ideally I could create a HighCharts char or something that would look at least close to the one created by a user in Excel. At the moment, I'm looking into the Open XML / Drawing ML file formats or possibly VBA  to create a translation layer to some JavaScript charting lib e.g. HighCharts.

Note it's not just a case of exporting as a simple CSV file, the key consideration here is preserving the chart formatting..

Thanks for any suggestions,

A,

Comment: if you want to preseve chart formattng from excel, then what you're really asking for?

Comment: How are you reading the Excel workbook currently?

Comment: @MarkBaker I'm not reading it currently..the users create there charts in Excel..they're domain experts and know how to use Excel so I'd prefer to keep it that way and figure out a way to output the chart data / metadata to some other form that I can then parse...

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest an add-in called [Funfun](https://www.funfun.io/1/#/home), you can code some Javascript, HTML and css in Excel. It hosts an online editor with an embedded spreadsheet to make the transition easier to Excel.

I'm going to take a [bubble chart example from Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/bubble) and change the data, here is what I get:

https://www.funfun.io/1/#/edit/5a61c190404f66229bda3f0f

I store my data in the embedded spreadsheet, and thanks to a json file I can use it in my javascript code:

```
{
    "data": "=A1:E16"
}
```

I format my data in my script.js so I can directly load it in Highcharts (for numbers you must convert your data into floats or int):

```
var data = [];

for (var i = 1; i < $internal.data.length; i++)
  data.push(
    {
      x: parseFloat($internal.data[i][2]),
      y: parseFloat($internal.data[i][3]),
      z: parseFloat($internal.data[i][4]),
      name: $internal.data[i][1],
      country: $internal.data[i][0]
    }
  );
```

And you add your data in the chart:

```
series: [{
        data: data
    }]
```

You can of course change the settings of your chart (color, text, font, type of chart...).

Once you are finished, you can directly load it in Excel by pasting the URL in the [Funfun add-in](https://www.funfun.io/1/msaddin). Here is how it looks like with my example:

[image: final]

I used Highchart for my example, because you mentioned it but you can of course use many other powerful libraries like chart.js and plotly.js (for 3D charts).

**Disclosure : I’m a developer of Funfun.**

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript? This would be easier with server-side PHP plug-in's, unless the file is loaded client-side.

Please give more information about your situation

Comment: @fazo I'm looking to allow our users to create charts with certain labels and colours and then export the chart data and meta data to HighCharts ideally..

Comment: @dominicbri7 Basically, is there a way to serialise an Excel chart to say XML, where I can then parse it myself into the required form (JSON). Maybe it's possible to access the chart via VBA? All the examples concern making a chart with VBA. I want to access a chart that has alraedy been made (by a user), via VBA say, then output that chart in another form.

Comment: You still need to extract the chart definition/data from the Excel file... what version of Excel are your users working with (are they .xls or .xlsx files)?

Comment: @MarkBaker It'll be Excel 2007. To extract the definition and data, is it a case of using VBA, are there any examples of this? What about DrawingML / Open XML

Comment: If it's Excel 2007, then the chart information is maintained in the /xl/charts/chartN.xml files when you unzip the .xlsx file... however, to read style information as well, you'll need to extract that from /xl/styles.xml. It can be quite a convoluted process. I've been working on reading/writing charts from Excel files for the next release of PHPExcel, so I know it's not quite as simple as just reading an XML file, but it can be done

Comment: Ok, and what about the VBA approach e.g. traversing the object hierarchy and writing a serialization routine to create a JSON or XML file with just the necessary info?